# When to add_filter() to Custom Query

Tags: wp-query, filters

I have complicated query where I need to join multiple tables. I'm doing that via `add_filter('posts_join')` - my question is, when and where do I add the filter so that it only applies to the custom query?

My Custom Query

```
$test = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'artcpt', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'arttax', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => array(20,41,16)))));
```

Should I physically add the filter above the query or after? Do I need to put it into a separate file (function.php) and attach it another way? Do I need to do something with `query_vars`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add your filter before you create the query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'custom_posts_join' );
$test = new WP_Query( $args );
```

where you can define the filter callback in your theme files, for example
`functions.php` or in a plugin:

```
function custom_posts_join( $join )
{
    // modifications
    // $join = ...

    // remove the filter 
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // return the result    
    return $join;

}
```

Notice that we remove the filter with this line:

```
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
```

so it will not affect other queries.

Comment: you post my exactly question 20 seconds before :) I deleted the mine and +1 the your. :)

Comment: @G.M. hehehe, thanks, but I was just trying to upvote your answer and was going to remove mine since it was very similar, I guess we had the same idea at the same time ;-)

Comment: What if the query is automatic? Like an archive template page, would I put the filter before wp_head()?

Comment: If you want to filter the main query, you can for example add the above filter within a pre_get_posts action callback.